# How to make R listen to messages from Discord

Tags: shiny, discord.js, discord.py, webhooks

Any suggestion on how to make R listen remotely to Discord messages as they arrive (by this I mean not needing to have the Discord console open or even installed in a local machine)?

The function GET from the httr package can be placed inside a infinite loop that queries new messages at certain time intervals. This is not optimum as many times there may not be new messages, overloading the networks.

The solution appears to be to use websockets. They work as shown in this R [application](https://tradermade.com/docs/streaming-data-api#wsR), but I have not manage to get it to work for Discord.

The code below works for the given webpage, as the data provider provides a wss:// webhook. Discord only provides httr:// webkooks.

```
library(websocket)
library(jsonlite)


     {
      ws <- WebSocket$new("wss://marketdata.tradermade.com/feedadv")
      ws$onMessage(function(event) {
        d <- event$data
        if (d != "Connected"){
          json = fromJSON(d)
      cat("", sep="\n\n")
      cat(" Symbol ", json$symbol, json$ts, json$bid, json$ask, json$mid) #cat

    }
  })
  ws$onOpen(function(event) {
    ws$send("{\"userKey\":\"wsHCUHTiyKpMtJFoR7nA\", \"symbol\":\"GBPUSD\"}")
  })
}
```

I implemented  the code below using the Discord [Gateway](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway-events), and hacking a Python function from the Discord.py [module](https://pypi.org/project/discord-gateway/) (Not an expert on python). The code effectively can get a message from Discord to R in real-time, but has a couple problem. 1) I could not set the heartbeat, so the connection expires after about 40 seconds. 2) It requires to have the Discord console open; basically, one cannot get messages remotely...your Discord console has to always be open.

Any suggestion on how to have R listen remotely to Discord messages as they arrive?

```
library(websocket)
library(jsonlite)

LastTime=Sys.time() #This is a timer to keep connection open

{
  ws <- WebSocket$new("wss://gateway.discord.gg/?v=9&encording=json")

  #Jason container of data to get into Discord
  token="YOUR_TOKEN"
  Rpayload = list(
  op= 2, 
  d= list(
  token= token,
  intents= 513,#tell that we want the messages.
  properties=list(
    os= "windows",
    browser= "firefox",
    device= "firefox")
  )
 )
  
  #message sent every few seconds. to keep connection alive
  KeepAlive = list(
    op= 2,
    d= "null"
    )

  #first load of data to connect
  Jsonpayload =toJSON(Rpayload, auto_unbox = TRUE, pretty = TRUE)
  #load of data for keeping connection open
  JsonKeepAlive =toJSON(KeepAlive, auto_unbox = TRUE, pretty = TRUE)

  #function for delivering first laod of data to connect
  ws$onOpen(function(event) {
  ws$send(Jsonpayload)
  })

  #What to do when new message arrives
  ws$onMessage(function(event) {
    d <- event$data #this is the data received from Dircord
    json = fromJSON(d) #Convert to readable format
    Heartbeat=json$d$heartbeat_interval/1000 #heart beat in seconds.

  #from the message received, collect only the content.
  Alert= (json)$d$content
  print(Alert) # print the content in R, to verify it works

  })

  #code to keep connection open...does not work, as implemented. The connection still expires every 40 seconds.
  TimeLapse=as.numeric(Sys.time()-LastTime)-10
  if(TimeLapse>=10){
    ws$send(KeepAlive)
    LastTime=Sys.time()
  }

  print(TimeLapse)
}
```

Comment: This isn't relevant to discord.js or discord.py.

Comment: discord.py does exactly want this post asks. Unfortunately, there is not analogous library in R. So, any user from Python that has implemented such a functionality will know the transformation that needs to be done, from https to wss, for this function to operate in R. In this case, the community from python could be of much help to the one from R.

Comment: Every single discord library does exactly what this post asks, the post is not related to discord.py in any way. This is the same as tagging something about for-loops as "Google Cloud" because one of the SDKs uses a generator somewhere internally. Most of the people using discord.py have no clue how it works internally & have no idea how to transform your code.